# Generate a text file based on Object of redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, text-files

I'm want to generate a text file with the data being captured in a form. I'm using react and redux. Im not sure where exactly this has to be done.

I set up my reducer so that the new state returns an object with the data being capture. [image]

I want to save the new state of the reducer which is an object to a text file

Action file:

```
export const SAVE_CONFIG = 'SAVE_CONFIG';


export function saveConfig(memberDemographic) {
    return {
      type: SAVE_CONFIG,
      memberDemographic
    };
}
```

Reducer file:

```
    import {
    SAVE_CONFIG
  } from '../actions/saveConfig';

export default function newGraph(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SAVE_CONFIG:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                member_demographic_section: action.sectionTest
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: You could JSON.stringify your application state and perhaps use HTML5 to download that as a text file? See this article for how to do that https://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/